# GTK apps don't respect compose key mappings

Tags: xorg, keyboard, opensuse, gtk, compose-key

I have compose key set up on my openSUSE Tumbleweed (KDE) to map `<apostrophe>` + `<c>` to `"ć" (U0107)`. I keep the rules in `~/.XCompose` and all the programs respect them (e.g. Kate, Terminal, IntelliJ, etc), *except* Firefox. It keeps mapping apostrophe+c to ç. I have tried replacing all the ç's with ć's in .XCompose, but still somehow ç appears. Where does Firefox read config from and how to make it work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, not so surprisingly, not a Firefox-specific problem, but rather GTK-wide (so others, such as LibreOffice, are impacted too). GTK doesn't handle input methods as one would expect, needing a separate config.

First, I needed to figure out which input method is used. `gtk-query-immodules-2.0` and `gtk-query-immodules-3.0` don't come with `gtk2-tools` and `gtk3-tools` which are installed by default, but require 32-bit versions, even on 64-bit systems (`gtk2-tools-32bit` and `gtk3-tools-32bit`). After installing the tools, running the query command revealed `xim` is not on the list of installed input methods, and I needed to install `gtk2-immodule-xim`, `gtk3-immodule-xim` and the 32-bit versions.

After making sure xim exists, the final step is to set GTK_IM_MODULE=xim and to export it in `~/.profile` (somewhat strangely, even if one deletes `cedilla.so` from `/usr/lib/gtk-*.0/[version]/immodules`, it still continues to use cedillas).